# Toggle state from custom state variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `reactstrap` `Collapse` component that I'm trying to `toggle` `state` from an external `Button` that sits within a loop of mapped items using custom state variables.

My question:

Why does it only `open` and not `toggle` the `collapse` component when I have the state on my `openCollapse` method to `setState` to `!state.collapse`?

My code:

```
// some_items.js (brief example)

// State
this.state = {
  toggleCollapse: false
}

// my custom state variable that I want to have toggle
openCollapse(itemId) {
  this.setState(state => ({
    [`toggleCollapse-${itemId}`]: !state.collapse
  }));
}

// mapped item with button trigger for toggling the collapse
<div key={item.id>
  <Button
     onClick={() => {
        this.openCollapse(item.id);
      }}
  >
    View Listed Item Info
  </Button>
  //
  // Some extra content that belongs here in between..
  //
  <ItemInfoCollapse 
    show={this.state[`toggleCollapse-${item.id}`]}
    item={item}
  />
</div>
```

```
// My item_collapse.js
class ItemInfoCollapse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      collapse: false,
      isOpen: this.props.show
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ isOpen: nextProps.show });
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ collapse: !this.state.collapse });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} className={this.props.className}>
        // Some JSX markup
      </Collapse>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Did you saw your code here it's wrong? `<div key={item.id>` Maybe you just paste it wrong. But check this :)

Comment: @EsdrasXavier just example mishap, I have too much code in between so I had to reconstruct it

Comment: Ok My bad about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What dictates whether your `Collapse` component gets open or closed is based on the `show` prop that you are passing into it from your parent component.

It appears you have everything set up correctly, with the exception of your state variable that you're using in your `openToggle` function - `!state.collapse`. I don't see the `collapse` variable anywhere which means it's undefined so it's actually running `!undefined` which always evaluates to true (you can test this in a browser console).

I think what you mean is `!state[`toggleCollapse-${itemId}`]` instead of `!state.collapse`

Comment: Awesome! Perfect!